# Regarding loading image in Android application

Tags: android, shell

I had developed an Android application. After entering the passcode my application will check whether customer is there in the database or not and then my application continues. during this process I want to keep an loading image  as not to be in still position. I had given code like this

```
login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

//ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
// progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
// progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
//progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
// progressDialog.setProgress(0); // set percentage completed to 0%
// progressDialog.show();               

DAO dbObj = DAO.getInstance(context);
```

But now the problem is loading image is running after my application started running. However, I want to run the loading image between login and start of application.

Comment: You mean by 'start of application', going to a new Activity right?

Comment: @MartijnVanMierloo   no with in the activity only after DAO dbObj = DAO.getInstance(context); code will check for the customer is there are not in database and continous...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hide/close/disable progresDialog at the end of initialization of your application. It will not disappear by itself. How it will know that you are finished?